# Need to move full record to new json file if any of the value is null/empty string using python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to move full record to json file if any of the value for that record is empty string/null using python. As I mentioned in my input data
in first record first_name and org_names has empty string to move that full record to error file(json format)
Need to develope in such way it can handle any number of columns

**Code Tried**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("Input_Files/find_error_record.json")
leng = len(df)
i = 0

for i in range(leng):
    for key in df:
        print(key, ":", df[key])
```

**Input File**

```
[
   {
      "parsed_address":[
         {
            "line":"jhxyzf"
         }
      ],
      "email":[
         "sanjak@tsp.ece.mcgill.ca"
      ],
      "first_name":"",
      "last_name":"",
      "org_names":[
         ""
      ]
   },
   {
      "parsed_address":[
         {
            "line":"wxy"
         }
      ],
      "email":[
         "javier.bargas@unibas.ch"
      ],
      "first_name":"javier a",
      "last_name":"bargasavila",
      "org_names":[
         "a",
         "bc"
      ]
   },
   {
      "parsed_address":[
         {
            "line":"united states"
         }
      ],
      "email":[
         "ramona.bere@gmail.com"
      ],
      "first_name":"ramona c silvestru",
      "last_name":"bere",
      "org_names":[
         "ase bucharest university of economic studies"
      ]
   }
]
```

**Error File:**

```
[
   {
      "first_name":"",
      "last_name":"Gupta",
      "org_names":[
         ""
      ]
   },
   {   
      "first_name":"",
      "last_name":"bere",
      "org_names":[
         "ase bucharest university of economic studies"
      ]
   }
]
```

**Output File:**

```
[
   {
      "first_name":"javier a",
      "last_name":"bargasavila",
      "org_names":[
         "a",
         "bc"
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
import json


with open('input.json', 'rb') as fp:
    jsondata = json.load(fp)

output_data = []
for data in jsondata:
    if all(data.values()):
        output_data.append(data)

error_data = []
for data in jsondata:
    if not all(data.values()):
        error_data.append(data)

with open('output.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(output_data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

with open('error.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(error_data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

**input.json**

```json
[
   {
      "parsed_address":[
         {
            "line":"jhxyzf"
         }
      ],
      "email":[
         "sanjak@tsp.ece.mcgill.ca"
      ],
      "first_name":"",
      "last_name":"",
      "org_names":[
         ""
      ]
   },
   {
      "parsed_address":[
         {
            "line":"wxy"
         }
      ],
      "email":[
         "javier.bargas@unibas.ch"
      ],
      "first_name":"javier a",
      "last_name":"bargasavila",
      "org_names":[
         "a",
         "bc"
      ]
   },
   {
      "parsed_address":[
         {
            "line":"united states"
         }
      ],
      "email":[
         "ramona.bere@gmail.com"
      ],
      "first_name":"ramona c silvestru",
      "last_name":"bere",
      "org_names":[
         "ase bucharest university of economic studies"
      ]
   }
]
```

**output.json**

```json
[
    {
        "parsed_address": [
            {
                "line": "wxy"
            }
        ],
        "email": [
            "javier.bargas@unibas.ch"
        ],
        "first_name": "javier a",
        "last_name": "bargasavila",
        "org_names": [
            "a",
            "bc"
        ]
    },
    {
        "parsed_address": [
            {
                "line": "united states"
            }
        ],
        "email": [
            "ramona.bere@gmail.com"
        ],
        "first_name": "ramona c silvestru",
        "last_name": "bere",
        "org_names": [
            "ase bucharest university of economic studies"
        ]
    }
]
```

**error.json**

```json
[
    {
        "parsed_address": [
            {
                "line": "jhxyzf"
            }
        ],
        "email": [
            "sanjak@tsp.ece.mcgill.ca"
        ],
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "org_names": [
            ""
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: with open('Input_Files/find_error_record.json', 'rb') as fp:
    jsondata = json.load(fp)

for dict in jsondata:
    for key,value in dict.items():
        output_data = [obj for obj in jsondata if obj[key] != ""]

print(output_data)

Comment: I have tried above code but output is wrong.

Comment: As you can see it works for me. Could you please add the code that you tried?

Comment: Why don't you try my code and let me know if it works or not?

Comment: I can't do hard codeing. If there are more than 10 columns it is not good to use that code.

Comment: if possible then add a complex example so that we can test our code

Comment: Updated my input data in question

Comment: It seems correct to me. I just add input and output in my answer. please check updated answer

Comment: Yes right but i can't use hard coded value in my code. when i am trying to change it's not giving correct answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236938/discussion-between-naveen-and-sabil).

Answer (score 0):

We can extract error file and outfile in json format, then changed to dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
  

f = open('Input_Files/find_error_record.json',) 
data = json.load(f)  
f.close()

### Output File:
empty_string = ""
Output_File_json = [x for x in data if x["first_name"] not in [empty_string]]
print(Output_File_json)
df_Output_File = pd.json_normalize(Output_File_json)
print(df_Output_File)


### error_file
empty_string = ""
error_file_json = [x for x in data if x["first_name"] in [empty_string]]
print(error_file_json)
df_error_file = pd.json_normalize(error_file_json)
print(df_error_file)
```

Comment: Hi thank for the answer but it will be hard coded and if we have more columns then code will not be flexible